# Laravel | Uploading picture adds a \ instead of a /

Tags: php, image, upload, laravel

I don't really know how to explain this, but i'll try.

In my UploadController i have the following:

```
class UploadController extends \Digitus\Base\Controllers\BaseController {

public function index()
{
    return $this->view->make('user.profile.picture');
}

public function update()
{

    $file = Input::file('file');

    $destinationPath = 'uploads/'.$this->user->id;
    $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
    $upload_success = $file->move($destinationPath, $filename);

    try
    {
        $user = $this->user;

        $user->image = $upload_success;

        if($user->save())
        {
            return $this->redirect->to('user/'.$user->username.'/profile');
        }

    } catch(\Exception $e) {
        return $this->redirect->to('user/'.$user->username.'/profile')->withErrors(array('login'=> $e->getMessage()));
    }


}
```

}

My problem here is: when i upload a picture, it results in "uploads/username\imagename.extension"
I've been searching the web for this, but couldn't find what i need.

What i want is, that the \ turns into a / so that i can actually use the image.

Does anyone know what i have to do?

And no, the following code also doesn't work:

```
$destinationPath = 'uploads/'.$this->user->id.'/';
```

Your input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You will be better of using a users `id` instead of `username` as folder name (unless you have strict rule that `username` can only be `0-9a-z`).

Comment: Good point! Just in case a user decides to edit his/her username ;)

Comment: But would you know how to change this \ into a / ?